# Finding a pdf of a Gamma Distribution when $Z=\mathrm{arccot}\,(z)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, gamma-distribution

I have been given  $X \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$, so that $X$ has pdf $$f(x)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}\exp(−\beta x)$$ for $x > 0$ and $0$ otherwise.
I have to find a pdf when $Z = \text{arccot}(x).$

I know for a fact that you have to do $f_Z(z)=f_X(\cot z)\cdot \lvert\cot'(z)\rvert$ but cant seem to get any further so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing more to do, except for saying that $0<z<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: but dont you have to then apply it to the gamma distribution??

Comment: yes, you apply it to the gamma distribution, but i don't see any simplification to be made (maybe except that you can write $|\cot'(z)|=\csc^2(z)$ getting rid of the minus sign)

Comment: In other words $f_Z(z)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\frac{\cos^{\alpha-1} z}{\sin^{\alpha+1}z}\exp\left(-\beta\frac{\cos z}{\sin z}\right)$, $0<z<\frac{\pi}{2}$